# Почему открывается дефолтный сайт?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2

Здравствуйте. Немогу понять почему открывается дефолтный сайт (индексный фаил) /var/www/html. Я создал собственный конфиг вида `domain.name.conf`, вот эти настройки в нем

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.name
ServerAlias www.domain.name

ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot /home/user/domain.name/public_html/public

<Directory /home/user/domain.name/public_html/public>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Затем включил его `sudo a2ensite domain.name.conf` перезапустил апач `sudo service apache2 restart` Захожу по айпи, и всеравно дефолтный сайт открывается с 000-default.conf. Почему? как это исправить?

Comment: Отключите дефолтный сайт: `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf `

Comment: *Захожу по айпи* — а надо по имени: `http://domain.name`

Comment: @aleks.andr спасибо. Сейчас попробую

Comment: @alexander barakin домен же еще не привязан к серверу. По айпи тоже должно заходить же

Comment: так «заходит» же. а чтобы отображался **нужный** сайт, http-сервер ведь должен узнать, какой **вам** нужен сайт. вот вы его и указывайте. а если доменной записи не существует или она ведёт «не туда», `/etc/hosts` — вам в помощь.

Comment: @aleks.andr Все заработало спасибо. Но теперь другая проблема. Почему то при заходе через браузер, он пишет `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /info.php on this server.` не в корень не заходит, не в фаил  info.php

Comment: а это уже совсем другой вопрос, который прямо на этом сайте задавался множество раз. // собственно, и текущий вопрос множество раз задавался, просто всем лень найти дубликат и отметить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это означает, что выше в конфигурации уже есть `VirtualHost` для того IP и порта, по которому вы обращаетесь. Какой выше - тот и в приоритете.

Варианты: удалить остальные виртуальные хосты, если они вам не нужны; перенести текущий выше остальных (или соответствующую директиву `Include`, если он так подключается); обращаться по конкретному имени, а не по IP.